# Securing against JS injection with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validationattribute

I would like to allow users to post HTML to a site but need to ensure that no Javascript is injected into the site.

So far I have created a validation attribute to check the incoming html for dodgy doings

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, 
    AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class CheckHtml : ValidationAttribute, IMetadataAware {

    private static Regex _check = new Regex(
        @"<script[^>]*>.*?<\/script>|<[^>]*(click|mousedown|mouseup|mousemove|keypress|keydown|keyup)[^>]*>",
        RegexOptions.Singleline|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Compiled);

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
        object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {

        if(value!=null
            && _check.IsMatch(value.ToString())){

            return new ValidationResult("Content is not acceptable");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Allow Html</para>
    /// </summary>
    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata) {
        if (metadata == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("metadata");
        }
        metadata.RequestValidationEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Is this going to be enough?
What do you do to check for such naughtyness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Microsoft AntiXSS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814). It boasts a `AntiXSS.GetSafeHtmlFragment()` method which returns the HTML stripped of all the XSS-badness.

As David has pointed out, a white list is always the way to go. AntiXSS uses a whitelist of HTML elements/attributes that are safe against XSS / filters out JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this going to be enough?

No. It is a blacklist. A blacklist is never enough.

No. It is a regular expression. Regular expressions are rubbish at dealing with arbitrary HTML.

> What do you do to check for such naughtyness?

A proper HTML parser combined with a whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Atwood had a nice discussion of this topic over on refactor my code. Definitely worth the time to check it out: http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html

The final refactored version should be pretty solid. Security is never a 100% type of thing but this is probably better than most other examples floating around.

Comment: thanks, the white-list would have to be updated for html5, but  that's a great start